# browser (IE, chrome) open plain text not html file

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 to write my testing html file. I save the text as HTML format.
Then when I try to open the file with browser by either drag&drop or Open_With...

Then.....

The browser open my plain text file, not the actual html.
This is what it look like. Just white background and these text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>A Hello World Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
```

This is my first time with html ever, do I have to do special setup with anything? I just use default SublimeText2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be because you are missing the main tag `<html>`.

Do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>A Hello World Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<html>` is the main tag, browser will look for to tell whether it is html or not.

Also make sure it is saved as `.html` or `.htm`

Comment: I didn't? I just try to click accept but miss click. It said I don't have enough reputation anyway. But this really work. Thank a lot. Also look like I have to put .html manually, the save as didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Sublime Text, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Type in `HTML` into the box and select `Set syntax: HTML`.

Then, in the file, type in `html` then press <kbd>tab</kbd> straight after and it should create a snippet (which is default):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Then make sure you save the document as `.html` or `.htm`.

This should work in your browser after.

**Note:** Setting syntax and doing snippet wont actually 'help' in terms of this question, but will help you in HTML by making things quicker and having syntax highlighting.